# How to avoid/disable vertical scrolling for Collection View in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collection view that is customized to show multiple column data. I am using a custom Collection view flow layout class to layout the cells of the column. The code is working fine, but during vertical scrolling, the layout of cells gets corrupted. In my case, the collection view should not allow vertical scroll because the view is resized to the size of the collection view content size. Also, I am displaying the collection view in the table view.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your flow layout's `scrollDirection` to `horizontal`

```
layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
```